# JWPlayer 6 multilanguage on android

Tags: android, jwplayer, http-live-streaming, m3u8, jwplayer6

Does anyone know if is multilanguage supported for Android?

I cannot find anything clear in this example regarding to the multilanguage on mobile devices https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1761348-multiple-audio-renditions

But this code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id='playerTest'></div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
          jwplayer('playerTest').setup({
            file: "some m3u8 file",
            androidhls:"true",
          })
        </script>
      <div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Which renders the multilanguage buttons in desktop doesnt render them in android.

Does the m3u8 must have some special syntaxis for Android? Currently I have something like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="Chinese",FORCED=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="eng.ttml",LANGUAGE="eng"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="aac",LANGUAGE="eus",NAME="Basque",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="/ts/out.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="aac",LANGUAGE="spa",NAME="Spanish",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="/ts/spa.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="aac",LANGUAGE="cat",NAME="Catala",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="/ts/cat.m3u8"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=688000,NAME="Main",CODECS="avc1.66.30",RESOLUTION=448x252,AUDIO="aac",SUBTITLES="subs"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Android does not support multiple audio and Embedded VTT captions in the manifest for mobile web. This is an HLS v4 feature, and Android only supports up to v3.

You can achieve this behavior in a native Android app: https://developer.jwplayer.com/sdk/android/docs/developer-guide/interaction/audio/

Comment: Thanks Josie for your response! I see in the link you provided the Audio Track switching is only supported for DASH and SmoothStreaming. Is it really possible then achieve that with a HLS?

Comment: Not yet, but we're currently working on a proof of concept for HLS that will be released to production within the next couple of months (again, for the native Android SDK).